# Finding the position of every one of a certain repeated char/substring in a string

Tags: java, string, char, substring

While it's painfully obvious what I'm trying to do, I'd prefer not to be told how to come up with the end result even if the way I'm going about it is wrong (Hints will be appreciated though). Anyways...

**Take for example, an 8 bit binary representation of a number in String format, "01110101". If I reverse the number, I get "10101110". If I wanted to find the positions of each 1 and add them to an array, how would I go about doing that? I tried to use indexOf('1'), but it keeps returning 0 or 1 as the index.**

Edit: By end result, I mean the overall goal I'm trying to accomplish with all of this, not the question I'm asking. I just wanted to keep someone from jumping in and telling me exactly how to convert from binary to dec rather than answering my current question...

Edit2: Okay, I'll be more specific. Basically, I'm trying to take a binary number(s), flip them around and get the positions of the ones and add them to an array. Then I'm going to try to iterate through the array, taking 2 to the power of each position and adding them up. Maybe not the most efficient way to convert from binary to decimal, but it's what I came up with.

Comment: Your problem with `indexOf('1')` is that it only returns the first occurrence of that character (as specified by the [String documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29)).

That being said, since you don't want any specific answers, Try thinking of different ways to represent your String. Look through the String documentation to see what methods you could invoke on it.

Comment: hint hint charAt(index)

Comment: as the others already pointed out, you can use the `string.charAt(index)` method to return you the character you are pointing at. All you have to do is loop through all characters of your string and test if they are 1 or 0 .. or what ever you may expect. But if you want the hints to be more concrete I can give you some code of course

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure how that applies though. I'm looking to find the positions of the 1s not test for whether they're 1s.

Comment: well while looping through the string you will know the index. Like: `for(int i=0;i<myString.length; i++){ if(myString.charAt(i).equalsIgnoreCase("1"){ // i is the position of the next 1}}`

Comment: Oh, I see. Okay, I'll try to figure that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,%20int)

Find the first, use that as the starting point for finding the next, lather, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a StringTokenizer to scan char by char while iterating through each.

```
  StringTokenizer s = new StringTokenizer("0101010111101");
  ArrayList index = new ArrayList();
  int count;

  while(s.hasMoreTokens){

       String num = s.nextToken();

       if(num.equals("1")){
           index.add(count);
       }count++;

  }
```

Comment: use `num.equalsIgnoreCase("1")` to test the equality of two Strings. `equals()` tests if the two `Objects` are the same (not if they have the same content)